# Standard way to create a Locale.LanguageRange from a Locale in Java

Tags: java, localization, java-8

In Java is there a way to create a Locale.LanguageRange from a Locale?

At the moment I do this:

```
List<LanguageRange> ranges = 
        Locale.LanguageRange.parse(
                locale.toString()  // locale.toString() gives en_GB
                .replace('_', '-') // parse() needs en-GB
                + ";q=1.0");       // weight
```

It feels dirty and very inelegant.

Is there a better or even standard way to do so? I wasn't able to find one.

Minimal working example:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Locale.LanguageRange;

public class LanguageUtil {
        public static Locale getClosestMatch(Locale locale, Locale defaultLocale, Collection<Locale> allowedLanguages) {
            List<LanguageRange> ranges = Locale.LanguageRange.parse(
                    locale.toString().replace('_', '-') + ";q=1.0," +           //exact match e.g. en-GB -> en-GB
                    locale.getLanguage() + ";q=0.5," +                          //close match e.g. en-US -> en-GB
                    defaultLocale.toString().replace('_', '-') + ";q=0.0"));    //default match e.g. fr-FR -> en-GB
            return Locale.filter(ranges, allowedLanguages).get(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `new LanguageRange(locale.toLanguageTag())` to derive a `LanguageRange` from a `Locale` which takes care of the syntax.

However by feeding this to `Locale.lookup()` the matching is to restrictive (it would not return `en_GB` for `en`).

I therefore ended up with a two-step mechanism:

1. `filter` all system locales by the requested locales
2. `lookup` the best match from result list of step 1 against the supported locales

Source code:

```
List<Locale> allAvailableLocales = Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales());

private Locale findBestMatch(final List<Locale> requested, final List<Locale> supported) {
    final List<LanguageRange> languageRanges = toLanguageRanges(requested);

    final List<Locale> allMatches = Locale.filter(languageRanges, allAvailableLocales);
    final Locale bestMatch = Locale.lookup(toLanguageRanges(allMatches), supported);

    return bestMatch;
}

private static List<LanguageRange> toLanguageRanges(final List<Locale> locales) {
    final ArrayList<LanguageRange> languageRanges = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Locale locale : locales) {
        languageRanges.add(toLanguageRange(locale));
    }
    return languageRanges;
}

private static LanguageRange toLanguageRange(final Locale locale) {
    return new LanguageRange(locale.toLanguageTag());
}
```

Note: consider a default in case `findBestMatch` returns `null`.

Comment: With this method, and also with the *Performing Language Tag Lookup* example code on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/matching.html - I ran the following test: 1. set both `allAvailableLocales` and `supported` to a list of locales represented by "en-US", "de-DE", "fr-FR", "zh-CN" and "en-GB". 2. set `requested` to list of locale represented by "fr-CA". Both the code examples (this answer and also, the one in the linked tutorial) return `null`. Does it not make sense to return "fr-FR" locale as best match for "fr-CA"?